# Reading a file with FileReader in NgRx / Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have a component of an input file like so:

```
<input id="file" type='file' (change)="_uploadFileChange($event.target.files)"/>
```

It then gets passed to the components TS code:

```
@Output() uploadFileChange = new EventEmitter();
    _uploadFileChange(file) {
        this.uploadFileChange.emit(file[0]);
    }
```

I have an action implemented like so:

```
export class UploadFileChange implements Action {
    readonly type = ActionTypes.UploadFileChange;
    constructor(public payload: File) { }
}
```

The side effect grabs it like so but isn't working or outpts anything to the console:

```
 @Effect()
    uploadFileChange$ = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(WActions.ActionTypes.UploadFileChange),
        map(action => {
            console.log('a');
            console.log(action['payload']);
            console.log('b');
        })
    );
```

I need to read the contents of the file without going to the server like with FileReader.

**EDIT/UPDATE**

The dispatch:

```
        this.store.dispatch(new WSActions.UploadFileChange());
    }
```

I now get the 'An arguement for payload was not provided.' error.

Comment: You seem to be missing the code where you dispatch the action. Using emit on an EventEmitter doesn't dispatch an action. That's clear in the [docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/actions).

Comment: Yeah I just realized that!

Comment: Added that in. Now getting an error. Still missing something.

Comment: Makes sense. If you're going to dispatch an action that requires a parameter, you need to pass that in. In this case, you need to pass in a File parameter.

Comment: yeah that worked. having issues with the FileReader as payload is undefined.